# Jekyll config.yml did not find expected key while parsing a block mapping

Tags: yaml, jekyll

I'm getting this error in the command line terminal:

> did not find expected key while parsing a block mapping at line 18 column 7

My jekyll _config.yml YAML file looks like this:

```
title: Oliver Williams - Portfolio
url: "http://yourdomain.com" # the base hostname & protocol for your site

# Build settings
markdown: kramdown
permalink: /:title

defaults:
  -
    scope:
      path: "" # an empty string here means all files in the project
      type: "posts" # previously `post` in Jekyll 2.2.
    values:
      layout: "post"

       -
    scope:
      path: "" # an empty string here means all files in the project
      type: "pages" 
    values:
      layout: "page"
```

Comment: These errors are fickle and it often reports the wrong line.

Comment: Fickle yaml errors I resolved by going back to tab delimited text for one project.

Comment: I had the same error but because I had added an apostrophe in one of the string configs and the formatting went crazy since we also use apostrophe to mean start/end of string. I just needed to replace the apostrophe at string start/end to a double quote sign and then the apostrophe sat comfortably within the string config.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not sure of your formating/indentation for _config.yml.

This one is correct :

```
title: Oliver Williams - Portfolio
url: "http://yourdomain.com"
markdown: kramdown 
permalink: /:title

defaults: 
  - 
    scope: 
      path: "" 
      type: "posts" 
    values: 
      layout: "post"
  -
    scope:
      path: ""
      type: "pages" 
    values:
      layout: "page"
```

Answer (score 6):

The problem is in your second list element for defaults. The marker is indented too much, possible because you used a tab instead of a two spaces.

There is no reason to put the mappings that are elements of those lists on a separate line. You also don't have to indent list elements if the list is a mapping value. Nor is it necessary to quote simple scalars like `"posts"`, `"page"`, etc. (You don't have that for your `title` value either)

So you can do:

```
title: Oliver Williams - Portfolio
url: http://yourdomain.com   # the base hostname & protocol for your site

# Build settings
markdown: kramdown
permalink: /:title

defaults:
- scope:
    path: ''         # an empty string here means all files in the project
    type: posts      # previously `post` in Jekyll 2.2.
  values:
    layout: post
- scope:
    path: ''         # an empty string here means all files in the project
    type: pages
  values:
    layout: page
```

which is equivalent to your input (corrected for the overindented `-`)

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere in your YAML, you have extra spaces (or not enough spaces) before a key value.

this YAML linter may help as it tells you a correct line with error(if any): https://jsonformatter.org/yaml-formatter.

Answer (score -1):

I had to replace "but wait, there's more!" with "but wait, there is more!", which was actually enclosed in single quotes, the apostrophe in the text string breaking it!

Comment: Your answer is unrelated to the problem in the question.

Comment: It related to the commenter "vishwarajanand Jun 13, 2019 at 13:12" which was the solution to and clarification of the problem we evidently had that brought us both here.